# Require inline action be sent by contract, and not account

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, inline-action

I have contractB trigger an inline action:

```
  /// @abi action
  void send() {
    action( permission_level{ _self, N(active) },
           N(contractA), N(get),
           std::make_tuple( _self )
    ).send();
  }
```

Now, when contractA receives the `get` action, as it currently is, the `user` will simply be `contractB`--which could mean either the contract triggered the action or the contract account.

I don't want this.  I would like for contractA to only allow contractB's contract to send the action.  Something like `user == contractB.code`, but have no idea how to check for this distinction.

EDIT:

I tried having `require_auth2( N(contractB), N(eosio.code) );` inside of the contractA action, but got the following error:

```
Exception Details: 3050000 action_validate_exception: Action validate 
exception inline action's authorizations include a non-existent permission: 
{"actor":"contractB","permission":"eosio.code"}
```

Comment: one way would be to extend the `get()` method to `contractA:get(account_name account, bool from_contract)` and create logic in `contractB` to send the appropriate flag in `std::make_tuple(_self, is_contract)`, but there may (possibly) be a different way to do this by modifying the `EOSIO_ABI` macro if you don't mind adjusting the autogenerated `.abi` file as well

Comment: Wait.  This doesn't prevent the user from sending the transaction with the from_contract=true.  What I am trying to accomplish is an action that can only be done via the contract.

Comment: but if the user pushes an action directly to contractA with `from_contract=true`, the account_name will be their account and not contractB so contractA can detect this

Comment: Ah.  There is a misunderstanding.  I am talking about the user being the owner of the account, contractB.  I want to know the difference between the user contractB and the contract, contractB.  I want ALL users to have to follow the code of a given contract, and that includes the contract owner as well.  As of now, since I can't distinguish between the contract owner and contract in an action, this means the contract owner could bypass the intended contract logic (which should not be possible without a contract update--which would have other implications).

Comment: oh hmm, then perhaps you can use something that checks permissions? inline actions triggered by contracts execute with \@eosio.code permission rather than \@active. can't check right now myself

Comment: Right, that is hopefully what someone will be able to answer with.

Comment: I tried the following in contractA: `require_auth2( N(contractB), N(eosio.code) );` but got a permission error `Exception Details: 3090004 missing_auth_exception: Missing required authority
missing authority of contractB/eosio.code` Maybe getting close

Comment: @Tyrick did you send the action from `contractB` with `permission_level{ _self, N(eosio.code) } ` as well?

Comment: @AndresBerrios, Good catch!!! I actually didn't.  But after correcting for that, I now get: `Exception Details: 3050000 action_validate_exception: Action validate exception
inline action's authorizations include a non-existent permission: {"actor":"contractB","permission":"eosio.code"}`

Comment: hmm I don't understand very well how they implemented that honestly. Maybe a search on the EOSIO/eos github issues for "eosio.code" can yield some results, as you would find what the devs discussed about it

Comment: i think the `unpack_action_data()` function may also help with debugging but I'm not sure about the solution either

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE**: This is the code I used to experiment with all combinations of permissions I could come up with: https://github.com/andresberrios/permissions_test

---

After a lot of experimentation, I finally understand how permissions work in EOSIO!

### EOS Permission Model - Overview

- An account can have various permissions (like owner and active), which are represented by an account@permission pair.
- Permissions (which are like roles) can be linked to specific actions of specific contracts to allow those permissions to execute those actions (`linkauth`). By default, the `owner` and `active` permissions can do anything except `active` can't change the owner permission.
- Permissions are controlled by an "authority", which is the multisig configuration of who can give that permission (in other words, who can act under that role).
- Within this multisig configuration, you can have a combination of public keys and other permissions (account@permission pairs), which makes permissions an intrinsically recursive construct.

### Acting as another account

Contracts in general should use `require_auth(account)` and not `require_auth2(account, permission)` unless there is a very specific reason to do so. Using `require_auth2` to require a specific permission of an account can hinder the configurability of the EOSIO permission system. This is because in general, if actions simply require the auth of an account, then that means they are implicitly requiring one of the following permissions of that account:

1. The `owner` permission.
2. The `active` permission.
3. Any other custom permission that the user decided to create for their account in order to give granular authorization to specific contract actions.

Point 3 means that a user can create a permission (as I mentioned, it can be seen as a "role") called for example `ramtrader` and then use `linkauth` to authorize that permission to use the `eosio::buyram` and `eosio::sellram` system contract actions. This can work with any contract, not only the system contract. This way, when defining the `ramtrader` permission, users will need to specify an *authority* for it (a multisig configuration), and this authority could specify that the only object that can act under this permission is `accountb@active`, for example, giving access to the `accountb` account to buy and sell RAM for `account`.

### Contract code acting as another account

Now that we understand how to act as another account, we can figure out how to allow a contract's code to act as another account, be it for transferring funds (`eosio.token::transfer` action) or just calling another contract's actions.

When contracts call inline actions, they are supposed to send the right permissions for that action. If for instance a contract that lives in the `contract` account would try to buy RAM for `account` using the funds of `account` itself, it would need to provide the same permissions that `account` is required to provide when they buy RAM for themselves manually. If we use the `account@active` permission, then the contract would need to send that permission in the inline action, and not `contract@eosio.code` as many of us could end up thinking (the documentation on this is very scarce and confusing). In order for the code in the `contract` account to be able to provide that permission, first `account` would have to add authorization for the code of `contract` to the authority (multisig config) that rules it's `account@active` permission.

This can be achieved by adding the `contract@eosio.code` permission to the authority, which is a special permission defined by the EOSIO software to specify that **only the contract code of the `contract` account** will be able to act under the permission (role) ruled by that authority. This means that the `account@active` authority would contain the public key that the owner of that account controls, as well as the `contract@eosio.code` permission.

This effectively implements what you were looking for: Authorizing a contract's code to act as another account, but not letting the contract's account act as the other account.

If you wanted to let a contract's account act as yourself but not the contract's code, you would have to do the same thing but instead of setting `contract@eosio.code` you would set `contract@active` or some other more specific (limited) permission.

### Setting up the permission authority

To configure your account to allow `contract@eosio.code` to act on your behalf, you would need to issue a transaction to the `eosio::updateauth` action with the properly formatted authority data. One way to do it using `cleos` is what @confused00 showed in his example:

```
cleos set account permission <YOUR_ACCOUNT> active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "<YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY>","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"<CONTRACT_ACCOUNT>","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p <YOUR_ACCOUNT>
```

It might be easier to save a `data.json` file and then put the payload in there and point `cleos` to it:

> data.json

```
{
  "threshold": 1,
  "keys": [
    {
      "key": "<YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY>",
      "weight": 1
    }
  ],
  "accounts": [
    {
      "permission": {
        "actor": "<CONTRACT_ACCOUNT>",
        "permission": "eosio.code"
      },
      "weight": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

and then:

```
cleos set account permission <YOUR_ACCOUNT> active data.json owner -p <YOUR_ACCOUNT>
```

Comment: what is the working code that works based on this method and does what op is asking for? I'm trying to run different versions to see how it works

Comment: I'll post some code tomorrow when I get back on the laptop.

Comment: @confused00 I updated the answer to add the link to the code.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
$ mkdir -p project/sender
$ mkdir project/recipient
$ touch project/sender/sender.cpp
$ touch project/recipient/recipient.cpp
```

**sender.cpp**

```
#include<eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include<string>

using std::string;
using eosio::contract;
using eosio::permission_level;
using eosio::action;

class sender : contract {
    public:
        sender (account_name account) : contract(account) {}

        void send(account_name account, string message) {
            action(
                permission_level(account, N(active)),
                N(recipient),
                N(receive),
                message
            ).send();
        }
};

EOSIO_ABI(sender, (send))
```

**recipient.cpp**

```
#include<eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include<string>

class recipient : eosio::contract {
    public:
        recipient(account_name account) : eosio::contract(account) {}

        void receive(account_name account, std::string message) {
            require_auth2(account, N(eosio.code));
            eosio::print(message);
        }
};

EOSIO_ABI(recipient, (receive))
```

**cleos & eosiocpp**

```
$ cleos wallet unlock
$ cleos wallet keys
[
    "EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV"
]
$ cleos account create eosio sender EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV
$ cleos account create eosio recipient EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV
$ eosiocpp -g project/sender/sender.abi project/sender/sender.cpp
$ eosiocpp -o project/sender/sender.wasm project/sender/sender.cpp
$ eosiocpp -g project/recipient/recipient.abi project/recipient/recipient.cpp
$ eosiocpp -o project/recipient/recipient.wasm project/recipient/recipient.cpp
$ cleos set contract sender project/sender
$ cleos set contract recipient project/recipient
$ cleos set account permission sender active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"sender","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p sender
```

Afterwards,

```
$ cleos push action sender send '["sender", "my_message"]' -p sender
```

goes through fine, while

```
$ cleos push action recipient receive '["sender", "my_message"]' -p sender
```

fails with missing authority.

So this setup allows 2 contracts to communicate between each other, but the recipient only allows messages from contract and not from the account

Comment: Nice solution, I was experimenting with this as well. I noticed you are sending only the message in the inline action call, but the receive action expects 2 params. I proposed an edit to your answer just to add it in there but I'm not really sure if it should be the `account` variable or `_self`.

Comment: Thanks! However, it doesn't work for me if I send the account as well... I think the message data is packed and sent over properly, while the account name is somehow passed through the `permission_level` I assume. I can remove the tuple packaging though as it doesn't do anything. Does it work for you with the suggested edit?

Comment: I tried a lot of different stuff, but I didn't try to reproduce your exact same code, so I'm not sure what's going on but it seems like maybe the `receive` action might not be actually handled by the `receive` method. According to my research, `require_auth2(account, N(eosio.code))` should fail. Are you getting the console output from `eosio::print(message)`?

Comment: Yeah, works fine. The action is made to the `receive` method

Comment: This is it!  Such an interesting solution.  It seems that the eosio.code permission is not default to accounts, and not "virtual" as I've been reading.  Seems you need to explicitly set the permission for the account.

Comment: @Tyrick I explained it all in detail in my answer. In a way, it **is** virtual in the sense that it's provided automatically by the contract code when calling inline actions, but it needs to be authorized manually on your account to allow it to act on your behalf.

Comment: @confused00 I followed your instructions step by step and it gives me this error when pushing the action: `assertion failure with message: read
    {"s":"read"}
    thread-0  wasm_interface.cpp:930 eosio_assert`

Comment: @confused00 it seems related to this issue: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4394 so it's probably because of missing or wrong parameters when calling the inline action.

Comment: @confused00 yep, I changed it to `std::make_tuple(account, message)` and now I get `missing authority of sender/eosio.code`, but the authority was set properly, so this doesn't really work.

Comment: hmm works fine for me. did it work for you @Tyrick?