# How do I ensure my Action Listener responds only to authentic senders?

Tags: action, transfer

I have an apply function that listeners for transfers to my contract from eosio.token. On notification of a transfer, a function (buy) is called within the contract. How do I ensure that this "buy" function cannot be called manually, by faking the transfer strut? I am concerned it is possible to supply a false ".from=eosio.token", when no tokens were actually transferred.

Comment: it's easy, don't add the buy to your abi, or don't add the buy to your EOSIO_ABI MACRO

Comment: I suspected as much. This means the action listener does not require the abi then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that you can prevent this:

1. You remove the `buy` function from the ABI, it can therefore never be called manually, but only through another function that is part of the ABI.
2. You restrict access to the `buy` function to only be accessible by the contract itself, using `require_auth(_self)`.

Ideally do both, as you can never be too safe...

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the "buy" (you can just leave that out of the ABI), it is calling "transfer" directly - not by way of eosio.token.  The "transfer" function must be part of the the ABI macro or it won't accept require_recipient calls from eosio.token - I just verified this to be sure.

So then the question I believe you are asking is how to I check that the require_recipient carbon copy actually came *from eosio.token*.  I believe the answer is to check as follows:

```
require_auth(from);
require_auth2(N(eosio.token), N(eosio.code));
```

Also some discussion of this here worth reading:

[Require inline action be sent by contract, and not account](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/require-inline-action-be-sent-by-contract-and-not-account)