# How to tell if a transaction was initiated by account or contract code

Tags: deferred-transactions, authorization

My goal is to get a list of account names of human users of a dApp, from the output of

```
cleos get actions <dApp account name> -j
```

Is there any way to determine, from a transaction's initial action's *authorization* and *auth_sequence* fields, whether the transaction was initiated by the account user(by signing the transaction with the active private key) or as a deferred action by the account's contract code?

The [closest answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/1718/2182) I can find details the authorization difference between contract-initiated and user-initiated transactions but I still have no idea of how to differentiate these by looking at a transaction JSON.

I thought of checking whether or not an account has non-0 code hash, but I'd be missing out on accounts that have contract code as well as being used by their owner to interact with the dApp.

Comment: Can you post an example transaction that displays the "authorization" and "auth_sequence" fields?  From there, I think I'll be able to answer the question.

Comment: When I run the command you have written above, I always get: `{
  "actions": [],
  "last_irreversible_block": LAST_BLOCK_NUMBER
}`. Regardless of whether I do it on an account with or without a contract attached./

Comment: What is the use case for it? The action' result should not be different if it is executed by a contract or account. How would you write that into a ricardian contract?

Answer (score 2):

If an action is initiated by user account, it will be included in the `trx.trx.actions` array of a transaction. Follow this idea, we could do:

1. We have a output actions list from your `cleos get actions <dApp account name> -j` command. We would like to know that, for each action in the list, is it a user action or an inline action. So we should iterate over the list and take one action a time.
2. Find the `trx_id` field of current action. This would be the transaction ID that this action belongs to.
3. Use `cleos get transaction <trx_id>` to get the transaction data. It should look like:

   ```
   {
       block_num: 30285537,
       block_time: "2018-12-04T06:19:54.500",
       id: "404f599bc56f16692313e9308e78276ccc5be1e873153088a2d08908af492fbe",
       last_irreversible_block: 30392225,
       traces: [{…}, {…}, {…}],
       trx: {
           receipt: {…}, 
           trx: {
               actions: [{…}]
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Look for current action in the transaction data. If it is in `trx.trx.actions`, it is a user action. Otherwise, if it's not in `trx.trx.actions` but in `traces`, it is an inline action. Or, you could also traverse over items in `traces`, testing if your current action's `global_action_seq` matches `receipt.global_sequence` of any child item inside of `inline_traces`.