# How can i prevent another contract call my contract's method?

Tags: smart-contract

how can i prevent another contract call my deployed contract?   Or how can i know that the caller is an eos account with contract or not.
Thanks.

Comment: maybe [this question](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1621/require-inline-action-be-sent-by-contract-and-not-account/1718) can help?

Comment: You can set the autority of actions accordingly .

Comment: @confused00 & Nirdesh  Thanks for your replies, i think i got some clue.